# Communicating through nodejs sockets ( from server to index.html)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets

I'm trying to emit a socket from my server.js and handle it in my index.html.
Here is my server.js code:

```
io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){
socket.on("send",function(data){

    mongodb.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase",function(err,db){
        if(err) throw err;
        var to_be_inserted = {name: data.name,content: data.content};
        db.collection("chat").insert(to_be_inserted,function(err,objects){
            if(err) throw err;

            var cursor = db.collection("chat").find();

            cursor.toArray(function(err,docs){
                socket.emit("data_to_be_printed",docs);
            });

        });
    })
})
```

})

In index.html I simply try to alert whenever the sockets gets emmited:

```
socket.on("data_to_be_printed",function(cursor){
                alert("at least this works");

            });
```

However I am not alerted. The find() method does return at least 5 objects in my console.

**UPDATE**
The send sockets does get emitted and the data does get inserted into the db. The only problem is that the data_to_be_printed sockets is not getting emmited

**UPDATE**
The way that I created the sockets in index.html is :

```
 <script src="http://127.0.0.1:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


       <script>
            var socket = io.connect("127.0.0.1:1337");
</scrip>
```

Comment: When you emit, is it printing the same thing(event name and data) on our server console ? and how did you created socket connection in index file ? that code would help more.

Comment: @Pranav I added the code that creates the sockets in index.html. I'm not sure what you mean by the printing though. Let me know if I can get you any more information

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I forgot to restarts my server.js.